# T-SQL use EXISTS as Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, exists

I'm wondering whether I can use EXISTS (or something similar) in column like this:

```
SELECT Column1,
       Column2,
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T2.Column = T1.Column) AS IsFlag
FROM Table1
```

I know I can do something similar with Count()

```
SELECT Column1,
       Column2,
       (SELECT Count(*) FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T2.Column = T1.Column) AS IsFlag
FROM Table1
```

But that might not be very efficient when Table2 is large

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Column1,
       Column2,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 T2 
       WHERE T2.Column = T1.Column) then 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsFlag
FROM Table1
```

Comment: There is a T1 missing after Table1. Otherwise, the = expression inside EXISTS has a syntax error.

Answer (score 8):

```
CASE 
    WHEN 
        EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T2.Column = T1.Column) 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
END AS IsFlag
```